# mysql problem in php 5.6 no database selected

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have problem with connect to mysql database with my php code in php 5.6

i have problem no database selected !

my code is

```
$GLOBALS["mysql_handle"] = @mysql_connect($config["hostname"], $config["user_database"], $config["password_database"], true);
    if( !isset($GLOBALS["mysql_handle"]) && (!$GLOBALS["mysql_handle"] || !@mysql_select_db($config["database_name"], $GLOBALS["mysql_handle"]) || !@mysql_query("set names utf8", $GLOBALS["mysql_handle"]) || !@mysql_query("set character set utf8", $GLOBALS["mysql_handle"])) ) 
    {
        $GLOBALS["mysql_error"] = mysql_error();
        mysql_close2();
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: fyi, from [the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php): "_This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and has been removed as of PHP 7.0.0. Instead, either the mysqli or PDO_MySQL extension should be used._". Maybe remove the `@` to see errors? How do you know it doesn't select a database?

Answer (score 0):

1. `mysql_` functions should no longer be used.  If you are writing new code for a project, take the time to modernize.  Use mysqli or pdo.

> Warning
>   This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ for more information. Alternatives to this function include:
>
> mysqli_connect()
>
> PDO::__construct()

2. The error suppressor `@`, it typically evidence of poorly written code.  Avoid using this technique.  Handle generated errors appropriately.
3. `isset()` makes two checks:

   - is the variable declared?
   - is the value not `null`?

Because you are declaring `$GLOBALS["mysql_handle"]` on the first line, it will always be set.

Because `mysql_connect()`:

> Returns a MySQL link identifier on success or FALSE on failure.

...the value will never be `null`.

So `!isset($GLOBALS["mysql_handle"])` will never evaluate as `true` and the following conditions will never be reached:

```
&& (!$GLOBALS["mysql_handle"]
    || !@mysql_select_db($config["database_name"], $GLOBALS["mysql_handle"])
    || !@mysql_query("set names utf8", $GLOBALS["mysql_handle"])
    || !@mysql_query("set character set utf8", $GLOBALS["mysql_handle"])
   )
```

Please read the php manual when you get stuck.

```
$GLOBALS["mysql_handle"] = mysql_connect($config["hostname"], $config["user_database"], $config["password_database"], true);
if (!$GLOBALS["mysql_handle"]
    || !mysql_select_db($config["database_name"], $GLOBALS["mysql_handle"])
    || !mysql_query("set names utf8", $GLOBALS["mysql_handle"])
    || !mysql_query("set character set utf8", $GLOBALS["mysql_handle"])
) {
    $GLOBALS["mysql_error"] = mysql_error();
    mysql_close2();
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

go to Manage User Privileges
and let your user access the specified database!